# How do I negate the parameter for AngularJS ng-if directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

Quick Example:

There is a routed parameter (/Home/:isLoggedIn) that equates to true or false. (/Demo/#/Home/false) and a controller property

*this.loggedIn = this.routeParams.loggedIn;*

I have a view (Home.html) that has two elements, each with an ng-if attribute.

```
<div ng-if="home.loggedIn">
    Logged In!
</div>
<div ng-if="!home.loggedIn">
    Not Logged In...
</div>
```

If I navigate to /Demo/#/Home/true then the first element displays and the second does not.
If I navigate to /Demo/#/Home/false then the first element does not display NOR does the second one.

I would expect the !home.loggedIn parameter evaluate to true when the value of loggedIn is, in fact, false.

Any advice here?

Comment: my guess: the `false` you get is represented as a string and not as a boolean, try to check this

Comment: Works for me.. http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKsLzgOnrfCEGvvPIFpR?p=preview

Comment: string it was...good call...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is quite obvious that he problem has its root to the fact that `routeParams.loggedIn` is a string.

So the solution is quite obvious:

```
// Change that:
this.loggedIn = this.routeParams.loggedIn;

// To this:
this.loggedIn = this.routeParams.loggedIn === 'true';
```

---

But why the weird behaviour ?
Why work not showing anything when `loggedIn` is 'false' ?

Well, here is why:

The `ngIf` directive uses the following `toBoolean()` function to convert its value to boolean:

```
function toBoolean(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    value = true;
  } else if (value && value.length !== 0) {
    var v = lowercase("" + value);
    value = !(v == 'f' || v == '0' || v == 'false' || v == 'no' || v == 'n' || v == '[]');
  } else {
    value = false;
  }
  return value;
}
```

If a string is passed to `toBoolean()` it converts it to lowercase and checks (among other things) if it equals 'false' (in which case it returns `false`). This is different than the default JavaScript implementation which interprets any non-empty string as `true` when casting to boolean.

So, let's examine the two cases for both `ngIf`s:

1. `loggedIn === 'true'`

   ngIf1 evaluates `home.loggedIn` --> 'true' (string)
   ngIf1 passes this value through `toBoolean()`
   `toBoolean('true')` returns **true** (because it sees a string that can't match with any string considered falsy)
   ngIf1 renders its content

   ngIf2 evaluates `!home.loggedIn` <=> `!'true'` --> false (boolean)
       (this happens because any non-empty string happens to evaluate to true)
   ngIf2 passes this value through `toBoolean()`
   `toBoolean(false)` returns **false**
   ngIf2 does not render its content
2. `loggedIn === 'false'`

   ngIf1 evaluates `home.loggedIn` --> 'false' (string)
   ngIf1 passes this value through `toBoolean()`
   `toBoolean('false')` returns **false** (because it sees a string that is considered falsy
   ngIf1 does not render its content

   ngIf2 evaluates `!home.loggedIn` <=> `!'false'` --> false (boolean)
       (this happens because any non-empty string happens to evaluate to true)
   ngIf2 passes this value through `toBoolean()`
   `toBoolean(false)` returns **false**
   ngIf2 does not render its content

So, this explains the "weird" behaviour (hopefully in an understandable way).

Comment: The function toBoolean() pretty much explained everything thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is likely home.loggedIn is a string, when passed to ng-if it is probably evaluating and doing the conversion from string to bool to get the value "false" into false.  In the expression evaluation before the value is passed through if you have !"false" that is actually false since any string is true, negating it becomes false.

Comment: then how do you explain this statement: "the first element does not display NOR does the second one". Neither of the two elements were displayed.

Comment: home.loggedIn should be true based on your premise.

Comment: agreed ExpertSystem's answer goes into greater detail