# Angular ng-if not true

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

Why doesn't this work.

`<li ng-if="!area"></li>`

Feels a bit illogical since

`<li ng-if="area"></li>`

works just fine.

'area' is defined in scope as true/false
Any workarounds for this? I would prefer not to use ng-show/ng-hide since both of them renders items in DOM.

Comment: It should work just fine the way you do it, do you have any more code examples?

Comment: Show your code where you define area in your controller. I suspect area is in fact truthy, not necessarily false.

Comment: possible duplicate of : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967847/how-do-i-negate-the-parameter-for-angularjs-ng-if-directive/> ? <-- where the comments and answers were related to evaluating a string vs a boolean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I negate the parameter for AngularJS ng-if directive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967847/how-do-i-negate-the-parameter-for-angularjs-ng-if-directive)

Comment: console.log($scope.area) and see if maybe the boolean true/false is maybe a string of "true/false" ;-)

Comment: The exclamation mark as negation worked fine for me.

Comment: what is your accepted answer ?

Answer (score 89):

use this

> ng-if="area == false"

OR

> ng-if="area == true"

this may help someone

Comment: Use ng-if="area==0" // False

Answer (score 7):

Use like this

```
<div ng-if="data.IsActive === 1">InActive</div>
<div ng-if="data.IsActive === 0">Active</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Just use for True:**

```
<li ng-if="area"></li>
```

**and for False:**

```
<li ng-if="area === false"></li>
```

Comment: <li ng-if="!area"></li> also works!

Answer (score 3):

**try this:**

```
<div ng-if="$scope.length == 0" ? true : false></div>
```

**and show or hide**

```
<div ng-show="$scope.length == 0"></div>
```

else it will be hide

-----------------or--------------------------

if you are using $ctrl than code will be like this:

**try this:**

```
<div ng-if="$ctrl.length == 0" ? true : false></div>
```

**and show or hide**

```
<div ng-show="$ctrl.length == 0"></div>
```

else it will be hide

Answer (score 0):

In angular 1, you can use `ng-show` and `ng-hide`.In your case, you would use `ng-hide`. For example:

```
<li ng-hide="area"></li>
```

Comment: The side-effect to this approach is that `ng-hide` will keep the elements in the dom, while `ng-if` does not render them at all.

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the $scope 
you must use $ctrl.area or $scope.area instead of area